# How to reset Azure Windows VM password deployed through Azure Resource Manager

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I want to reset admin password for my Azure VM running Windows deployed through ARM.

Answer (score 1):

Reset VM password deployed with ARM.

1. Download and install Azure CLI https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/xplat-cli-install/
2. Open command line and enter the following command:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI\wbin>azure login
3. Follow the instruction provided by command line
4. Select the Azure Subscription from which you want to reset the password for VM, Run command: Azure account  set "Subscription  Name" .
5. Run the command: azure vm reset-access -g [Resource Group name] -n [VMname] -u[username]  -p[newPassword].(don’t use square bracket while forming command ).Make sure you don’t have VmExtension installed for Microsoft.Compute.VMAccessAgent handler.